# How do I refresh points for a Heatmap Layer in Google Maps Android API utility library?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have this code but when I try to refresh the heatmap points, nothing happens. I don't know if I need something else, I've looked at examples but in my case it doesn't work. I'm using fragments.

Is there some other way to refresh a heatmap layer without rebuilding the map object?

```
public class tab2 extends Fragment{
 MapView mapView;
 GoogleMap MygoogleMap;

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mi_mapa);


mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    MygoogleMap = mapView.getMap();

    MygoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
    latitude = 18.916; 
    longitude = -99.236;


MygoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,
            longitude), 3.5f));
    return view;
}


public void setHotPoints(){

    Handler_sqlite_mapa helper = new Handler_sqlite_mapa(this.miContexto);
    helper.abrir(); //Abre la conexion a la BD
    String resultado[][] = helper.getTop(99);
    helper.cerrar();
    int lecturasConfirmadas=0;
    int columnas = (resultado.length);
    int filas = (resultado[0].length);
    Log.d("MiMapa:", "Columnas:" + columnas);
    Log.d("MiMapa:", "Filas:" + filas);

    if (mProvider == null) {
        List<LatLng> list = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        String valores = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
                if(resultado[3][i]!=null){
                    double la = Double.parseDouble(resultado[1][i]);
                    double lo = Double.parseDouble(resultado[2][i]);
                    list.add(new LatLng(la,lo));
                    lecturasConfirmadas++;
                }
        }

        if(lecturasConfirmadas>0){
            MygoogleMap.clear();
            mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder()
                    .data(list)
                    .build();
            mOverlay = MygoogleMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mProvider));
            mOverlay.clearTileCache();
        }

    }

}

}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "refreshing" the heatmap layer, but If you just wanted to remove the heatmap layer, you could use `mOverlay.remove();` and create a new layer, or you could change the dataset by using `HeatmapTileProvider.setData()` and `clearTileCache()`. If you haven't already checked out the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/heatmap), please do. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I tried it but when I use this.

mOverlay.remove();

TileOverlay eliminated but it can not be added again.

I have to flip the phone to re-create the object on the map to see the heatmap again.

I'm using this library.

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
}

Do you have an example where you remove and add  it?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there is any better approach, I am using remove and recreate to force update heat map:

```
    private void removeHeatMap() {
        mOverlay.remove();
    }

    private void addHeatMap() {

        mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder()
                .weightedData(samples)
                .build();
        mOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mProvider));
    }
```

One thing that I noticed is that if I didn't recreate the HeatmapTileProvider instance with the overlay, the heatmap will not be updated properly.

Answer (score 1):

clearTileCache odes the trick.

```
if(mHeatmapTileOverlay == null) {
    mHeatmapTileOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(options);
} else {
    mHeatmapTileOverlay.clearTileCache();
}
```